# "ORDER BY 'column_name' DESC", but numbers before letters requires two statements?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I want to select data in my database and order it alphabetically but numbers first and then letters.

Sample of my table:

```
                    watch_date
474 1442437 2181257 2015-12-20 Modern Family   3 13 Little Bo Bleep
475 1442437 2189485 2015-12-21 Modern Family   3 14 Me? Jealous?
476 1442437 2209159 2015-12-22 Modern Family   3 15 Aunt Mommy
477 1442437 2237415 2015-12-22 Modern Family   3 16 Virgin Territory
478 1442437 2244103 2015-12-22 Modern Family   3 17 Leap Day
479 1442437 2239817 2015-12-24 Modern Family   3 18 Send Out the Clowns
480 1442437 2305713 2015-12-24 Modern Family   3 19 Election Day
481 1442437 2305715 2016-01-02 Modern Family   3 20 The Last Walt
482 1442437 2247703 2016-01-03 Modern Family   3 21 Planes, Trains and Cars
483 1553656 2656658 unknown    Under the Dome  1  1 Pilot
484 1553656 2779640 unknown    Under the Dome  1  2 The Fire
485 1553656 2821206 unknown    Under the Dome  1  3 Manhunt
```

I want to order it using the fourth column (the column with dates and the text 'unknown' (it's called 'watch_date'))

The data in this column is either the text `unknown` or a date with the format `YYYY-MM-DD`

To do this I use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `watched_episodes` ORDER BY `watch_date` + 0 DESC, `watch_date` DESC
```

I thought the `+ 0` part added a 0 to all results, yet when I do not add the second ORDER BY statement:

```
`watch_date` DESC
```

it does put the numbers (dates) before the letters but it does not seem to sort the dates at all.

Comment: If watch_date is a string look into STR_TO_DATE

Comment: Store dates as dates, and unknown dates as NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, your query is simply wrong.  It should be giving an error because of the use of single quotes.  I'll assume you intend:

```
SELECT *
FROM watched_episodes
ORDER BY watch_date + 0 DESC, watch_date DESC;
```

This seems like a strange method.  If the values is always `'Unknown'` or a string in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, I would go for:

```
ORDER BY (watch_date = 'unknown'),  -- USE `DESC` to put `unknown` first
         watch_date DESC
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not know single quotes weren't allowed in a query, and I used them because the other quotes are already used for indicating a code block here on stackoverflow.com

Comment: As for the actual method used in your answer, this seems to be a lot cleaner.

Comment: @TheCodingWombat . . . They are allowed.  They represent string (and date) constants.

Comment: This does not work if value has number bigger than 10. .. Ut counts 10 as 1.

Answer (score 1):

**Use "union"**

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * FROM `watched_episodes` WHERE `watch_date` != 'unknown'
ORDER BY `watch_date` DESC
) table_alias
UNION SELECT * FROM `watched_episodes` WHERE `watch_date` = 'unknown';
```

You can order by whatever you want in subquery and still have the "unknown" rows after the actual date

**Tip** use "date" as column type of date format - so you can use date function without converting and just let the unknown be null.